# Type conversion without introducing a dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, type-conversion

I have 2 types:

- MyImmutableType
- MyDBType

I'd like to introduce a type conversion between the 2 types.
I see I can use [type conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) with implicit and explicit operators.

My problem is that I don't want to introduce a dependency of MYDBType inside my CommonTypes library.
How can I accomplish this? Possibly through extnesion methods? Without having to have my CommonTypes library know about my MyDBType library.

I can do extension methods, but I'm not sure how to do extension operator casts.

**Reason:**  The reason I want to not have a dependency is that I have a client/server architecture.  I don't want to distribute my DB class to my client users.  But I want my server side code to use a cast easily.

Comment: you may also consider mapping instead of casting

Comment: Could you point me to a link?

Comment: well something like http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define an implicit or explicit operator anywhere except in one of either of the two classes.

But you can certainly define a conversion method elsewhere, for example in a 3rd library.

The tricky part will be if you want to rely on certain details of one class that are private and therefore need to be handled within the class itself. But if that's the case you really aren't going to have any luck trying to do this without introducing a dependency, unless you want to resort to reflection (a valid alternative in some cases).

Comment: luckily all that I need is public, but I don't know how to do extension methods for casting operators.

Comment: "You can't define an implicit or explicit operator anywhere except in one of either of the two classes."  I guess this includes even extension methods.

Comment: @csharphelp: Yeah, unfortunately, you can't. The C# spec has very clearly defined rules about implicit and explicit conversion operators and there's not really any good way to fit extension methods into these rules. Any reason you feel strongly about using implicit/explicit conversion instead of supplying a simple conversion method?

Comment: Nope I had actually to do as you suggested but I wanted to search for the best way first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, Extensions methods are a really good approach for this. That you you can separate these method in a different class or even a namespace.

Comment: My question is how to use an extension method that has a cast operator, or if it is possible, how.

Comment: you can return one object from the other like this:
`public static MyImmutableType GetImmutableType(this MyDBType dbType)
{
  anything you need to get your immutabletype here...
}`

or the other way aorund

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really get away from a dependancy here. You can move the conversion to a factory/utility class, that way the types don't have to know about each other. Only the utility class has to have knowledge of both.

Comment: so just maybe a static class with static methods from 1 type to the other?

Comment: Thats what I would do. Easier to read for everyone else as well, yet has the exact functionality of an extension method.